# Avoid gradle build params for clean task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I configured my app level **build.gradle** file to pick the apk name from build parameters.

**Below is my build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somethind"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ....
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        changeAPKName(variant, project.apkName)
    }

    buildTypes {
        ......
        ......
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

def changeAPKName(variant, apkName) {
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File(apkName)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    ........
}
```

Now I can issue below command to build the apk with custom name

```
gradlew assembleDebug -PapkName=sample.apk
```

But the issue is if I have to clean the apk I have to pass the build params  to the clean command

**Below command is failing**

```
gradlew clean
```

**Below command is working fine**

```
gradlew clean -PapkName="somename.apk" //Its passing
```

How can I avoid passing build params to **clean** task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is we need to provide some default value to  `project.apkName`. So when we didn't pass apkName param from command line, it will take default value. It can be done like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somethind"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ....
    }

    def defaultApkName = "Pervacio_ssd.apk"
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if(project.hasProperty("apkName")){
            defaultApkName = apkName;
        }
        changeAPKName(variant, defaultApkName)
    }

    buildTypes {
        ......
        ......
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

def changeAPKName(variant, apkName) {
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File(apkName)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    ........
}
```